# How to extract key value from a JSON response in Java Language? I want to extract the value of "doj" but I'm not able to do so

Tags: java, json, parsing, key-value

```
{
    "reservation_upto": {
        "lng": 78.0098161,
        "lat": 27.1752554,
        "code": "AGC",
        "name": "AGRA CANTT"
    },
    "debit": 3,
    "doj": "28-05-2018",
    "to_station": {
        "lng": 78.0098161,
        "lat": 27.1752554,
        "code": "AGC",
        "name": "AGRA CANTT"
    },
    "response_code": 200,
    "boarding_point": {
        "lng": 80.2755685,
        "lat": 13.081674,
        "code": "MAS",
        "name": "CHENNAI CENTRAL"
    },
    "pnr": "4405474586",
    "chart_prepared": false,
    "journey_class": {
        "code": "3A",
        "name": null
    },
```

**THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED USING VOLLEY**

```
private void loaddata() {
    String url = "https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/pnr-status/pnr/4655474586/apikey/q15rfl3kpz/";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, 
         new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        JSONObject obj = null;
                        try {
                            String str="";
                            obj = response.getJSONObject("name");
                            str = String.valueOf(obj);
                            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                            tv.append(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What parser are you using? What problems are you facing? Can you show us your code attempt?

Comment: I have added the code I am using.
I have used Volley for parsing data

Comment: Where are you retrieving "doj"?

Comment: Looks like you can get a `Result<JsonObject>` from your `JsonObjectRequest`, extract the `JsonObject` from that result, then a `getString("doj")` from that jsonObject should do the trick. Note that I had no prior knowledge of Volley, I gathered that simply by looking at the javadocs of the different classes, which you should definitely do.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) object;    
String doj = (String) obj.get("doj")
```

You can use JSONObject `obj` to find out the value of key `doj`.

Latter on, if you want to have the doj as any other datatype you can parse in that. May be this could help. I don't have much idea on Volley :)